# How do I prevent an unassigned variable from displaying undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, undefined

I have a variable `let numbers;` And I have an eventlistener on a button, and when the button is pressed then the value of the button will be displayed.

```
let numbers;
function btnClick(event){


numbers += this.value
display.value = numbers

}
```

When I press for example 7 it will be displayed like this `undefined7`. What can I do to get rid of `undefined`?

Comment: Give `numbers` an initial value. Either zero or an empty string, I'm not sure what you need.

Comment: Also, if you want to do addition instead of concatenation, convert the input value to a number.

Comment: @user12137152 If `btnClick` is an event listener, `this` will be the same as `event.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you aren't initializing `numbers`, not only is it initially `undefined`, but there is no type associated with it. Later when you use `+=this.value` with it, the `value` of the button (which is a string) is used and because the `+` operator performs string concatenation when one of the operands is a string you get the original value for `numbers` of `undefined` concatenated with whatever the value of the button is.

To solve this problem, you should initialize `numbers` to some starting value and that value should be an implicit number so that when `+=` occurs, numeric addition will be performed instead of string concatenation. A value of `0` makes sense as it won't throw the math off:

```js
document.querySelector("[type='button']").addEventListener("click", btnClick);
const display = document.querySelector("[readonly]");

let numbers = 0;
function btnClick(){
  // The prepended + implicitly converts the string (this.value) to a number
  numbers += +this.value
  display.value = numbers;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="5">
<input readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator to assign the number and not add the undefined.

```
let numbers;
function btnClick(){
   numbers = numbers === undefined ? this.value: numbers += this.value;
   display.value = numbers;
}
```